# Making a custom datatype ord-able

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

Can someone explain to me how do I make a custom data type ord-able?

** I'm not allowed to make modifications to Suit itself, eg. deriving (Eq, Ord)

```
data Suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades deriving (Eq)
```

My Attempt:

```
instance Ord Suit where
    compare suit1 suit2 = compare suit1 suit2
```

but that seems to go on a continuous loop and doesn't halt.

Comment: Well you need to actually specify how this should be compared. I'm not aware of any universal way of deciding whether Hearts is greater than Clubs. Then you can use pattern matching.

Comment: I actually don't need them in any specific order, I just need them arranged next to each other.

Comment: Sorry? So you basically get to just choose some arbitrary ordering?

Comment: @jozefg Yeah, any arbitrary ordering would work for what I'm doing. For example, I just need [Diamonds, Clubs, Hearts, Diamonds] to be sorted/arranged as [Diamonds, Diamonds, Clubs, Hearts]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definition of Ord looks something like (but not quite)

```
class Ord a where
    compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
```

and `Ordering` has three possible values: `LT, EQ, GT`.

So, you need to define what the result of each comparison should be.  Something like:

```
instance Ord Suit where
    compare Clubs Diamonds    = LT
    compare Diamonds Clubs    = GT
    compare Diamonds Diamonds = EQ
    compare Diamonds _        = LT -- Diamonds are lower than everything besides Clubs and Diamonds
```

Your actual ordering may be different, but that should give you the basic idea.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can utilize the default ordering of strings to achieve something similar? (Considering I'm doing more of a grouping than sorting)

Comment: Could define it as an instance of show and then just do `compare = on compare show`

Comment: @jozefg It is already declared as an instance of Show, but how would I actually right the code out in Haskell? Example: `show Clubs    = "C"`

Comment: Yep, and then you have the same pattern matching that tredontho was talking about

Comment: @Jozefg, ok, I think I should have typed it differently. Is there anyway that I can `derive Ord` without actually making changes to the `Suit` declaration?

Comment: Yes, any of these methods do not require changing that

Comment: @jozefg Is there a direct equivalent of `data Suit = Clubs |.... deriving (Eq, Ord)` where I wouldn't need to individually state every possible comparison?

Comment: No, because the compiler is just doing that tedium for you with deriving

Comment: @user1043625, yes, there is. GHC has an extension, `StandaloneDeriving`. Its usage would look like this: `deriving instance (Ord Suite)` on the separate line. It will work just like usual `deriving`. See here: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/deriving.html#stand-alone-deriving

Answer (score 7):

A way to write a custom `Ord` instance where you don't have to spell out the result of each comparison is:

```
instance Ord Suit where
    compare a b = compare (relativeRank a) (relativeRank b) where
         relativeRank Diamonds = 1
         relativeRank Clubs = 2
         relativeRank Hearts = 3
         relativeRank Spades = 4
```

Here, you only need to mention each constructor once, and you can easily decide on a different ordering.

You can just as well use `compare Data.Function.on relativeRank`, but this is maybe easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [standalone deriving](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/StandAloneDeriving) with the same effect.

```
deriving instance Enum Suit
deriving instance Ord Suit
```